# Gradle is not adding Dagger 2 generated classes to aar

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-2, aar

I am new to stackoverflow so I am sorry if my question is no perfectly explained.

**My current project has the next structure**

```
                              core Library
                              |          |
                      Library 1         Library 2
                       |                 |
                    applications        applications
```

Core Library is a library which contains common functionality for the other 2 libraries.

In this case core Library, Library 1 and 2 use Dependency injection with Dagger 2, and each one of them creates it's own dependency graph. So each one of them has it's own component interface, modules, and Dagger 2 generated classes. Also all of them have @Inject annotations for obtaining their required object instances.

core library uses 2 classes to make the connection with the other libraries. An initializer class which builds the dependency graph and a publisher class wich has get methods that return the required object instances.

What I want to accomplish is to make 3 aar files, one for each library. And that Library 1 and 2 use the core Library aar. The applications take the library 1 and 2 from an artifactory repository.

My current problem is that in any of the 3 aar files are the Dagger 2 generated classes. I am not sure why. All the classes are been generated when i build the projects but the compiled classes are not inside the aar file.

**I am using:**

```
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.5'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.5'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

gradle-2.14.1

**This is an example of my publisher:**

```
public class Publisher {
@Inject
ReceiversManager receiversManager;
@Inject
NetworkManager networkManager;
@Inject
HttpRequestManager httpRequestManager;

public ReceiversManager getReceiversManager(){
    return receiversManager;
}

public NetworkManager getNetworkManager() {
    return networkManager;
}

public HttpRequestManager getHttpRequestManager() {
    return httpRequestManager;
}

public Publisher(){
    Initializer.getComponent().inject(this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with this script https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar

That script helps to create an aar with dependencies included which can come very handy in many situations.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).